# Failed to Process SQL Command - Oracle Job Scheduler

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, scheduler

I'm trying to set up a simple scheduled job with SQL Developer, but it fails to set the job up with the error message:-

Failed to Process SQL Command

The Developer Log gives me two entries ...

```
Level   Seq Elaps   Source                              Message
SEVERE  32  62  oracle.dbtools.scheduler.generator.DBMSSchedulerCodeGenerator   Can't find template CREATE_JOB_DESTINATION_CREDENTIAL.st
SEVERE  31  0   oracle.dbtools.scheduler.generator.DBMSSchedulerCodeGenerator   Can't find template CREATE_JOB_DESTINATION_CREDENTIAL.st
```

This is the Summary of code for the job, which is a simple update of one row in one table, which I wanted to test just once daily on a test instance

```
BEGIN
SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
        job_name => '"CHEROKEE_BACKUP".""',
        job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
        job_action => 'BEGIN
alter table drawing disable all triggers;
update DRAWING set proj_id = 1, site_id = 1, chg_num = 0, plant_id = 1, unit_id = 1, user_name = ''INTOOLS'', dwg_type_id = 1, chg_status = ''W'', chg_date = TO_DATE(''28-02-1995'',''DD-MM-YYYY''), dwg_num = 0, curr_rev_num = 0, dwg_title1 = '' '', dwg_title2 = '' '', dwg_title3 = '' '', dwg_name = '' '', ven_prop_by = '' '', ven_prop_date = TO_DATE(''28-02-1995'',''DD-MM-YYYY''), ven_dsgn_by = '' '', ven_dsgn_date = TO_DATE(''28-02-1995'',''DD-MM-YYYY''), ven_drwn_by = '' '', ven_drwn_date = TO_DATE(''28-02-1995'',''DD-MM-YYYY''), ven_ck_by = '' '', ven_ck_date = TO_DATE(''28-02-1995'',''DD-MM-YYYY''), ven_appr_by = '' '', ven_appr_date = TO_DATE(''28-02-1995'',''DD-MM-YYYY''), cl_ck_by = '' '', cl_ck_date = TO_DATE(''28-02-1995'',''DD-MM-YYYY''), cl_engr_by = '' '', cl_engr_date = TO_DATE(''28-02-1995'',''DD-MM-YYYY''), cl_appr_by = '' '', cl_appr_date = TO_DATE(''28-02-1995'',''DD-MM-YYYY''), area_id = 1, bmp_file_name = '' '', bmp_file_path = '' '', dwg_desc = '' '', output_dwg_fmt_id = 0, parent_id = 0, format_id = 0, rev_id = 0, eng_proj_id = 10, eng_ref_id = 10, merge_release_flg = ''N'' where dwg_id = 0;
alter table drawing enable all triggers;
commit;
END;',
        number_of_arguments => 0,
        start_date => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2014-07-15 14:45:46 America/Chicago','YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS TZR'),
        repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY',
        end_date => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2014-07-31 14:45:46 America/Chicago','YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS TZR'),
        job_class => '"SYS"."DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS"',
        enabled => FALSE,
        auto_drop => FALSE,
        comments => '');

SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
         name => '"CHEROKEE_BACKUP".""', 
         attribute => 'logging_level', value => DBMS_SCHEDULER.LOGGING_OFF);
SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
         name => '"CHEROKEE_BACKUP".""', 
         attribute => 'max_run_duration', value => INTERVAL '1' HOUR);
SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
         name => '"CHEROKEE_BACKUP".""', 
         attribute => 'schedule_limit', value => INTERVAL '1' HOUR);

SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable(
         name => '"CHEROKEE_BACKUP".""');
END;
```

What are the templates it's after? Why can't it find them? What haven't I set up properly?

Any guidance greater appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the templates that your error message mentions, but I can tell you that the PL/SQL block you run for your job is not valid and will not compile:

```
BEGIN
  alter table drawing disable all triggers;
  update DRAWING set proj_id = 1, site_id = 1, -- rest of line snipped
  alter table drawing enable all triggers;
  commit;
END;
```

This won't compile because `ALTER` cannot be used in PL/SQL.  To execute DDL such as `CREATE` `ALTER` or `DROP`, you need to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Also, DDL statements perform an implicit commit before and after execution, so the `commit` statement in your block is redundant.

Try the following instead:

```
BEGIN
  execute immediate 'alter table drawing disable all triggers';
  update DRAWING set proj_id = 1, site_id = 1, -- rest of line snipped
  execute immediate 'alter table drawing enable all triggers';
END;
```

Comment: Hi Luke, thanks for your input, really appreciated, after digging about a bit more I think it's more of a privilege issue, I was trying to set this up without being SYS/SYSTEM, I don't think it likes that!!